# Application starts with too high resolution

Tags: display-resolution, 22.04

Hej

I'm beginner and I want to move from Win to Linux.
I installed ubuntu and so far LabView as well

I would like to know why my App Labview 21 isn't scaled like it is in the display Settings

Ubuntu 22.04
Surface Book 3
Resolution 3240 2160 @ 200%

However the Application come like 100% which makes it unreadable and as a graphical programming tool useless. Simply can't see what I do.
See the print screen comparing the app with the icons and the browser window.

[Print screen resolution problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjIpw.jpg)

The drivers in use...
[display driver?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmgga.png)

Please help....

Thanks!

Comment: Problem with high resolution screens - for some apps it continues to be impossible to have them scaled, so they are rendered ridiculously small, only becoming useful if you run your entire system at lower resolution. The problem essentially is with these apps, not with the operating systems, though, but it would be nice if operating systems had a way to cope with this.